# How do I change the Go To Categories link in the term_updated_messages

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, custom-taxonomy, wp-admin

I have a custom taxonomy titled "shows". When a show gets updated it displays a message to the user followed by a link. I have already changed the message by using

```
add_filter('term_updated_messages', 'comment_updated_shows_messages');
function comment_updated_shows_messages( $messages ) {
    $messages['shows'] = array(
        0 => '',
        1 => __( 'Show added.' ),
        2 => __( 'Show deleted.' ),
        3 => __( 'Show updated.' ),
        4 => __( 'Show not added.' ),
        5 => __( 'Show not updated.' ),
        6 => __( 'Shows deleted.' ),
    );

    return $messages;
}
```

But I can not figure out where to change the link.

see screen shot

[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the link's *text*, URL or the entire link (i.e. the `<a>...</a>`)? If it's the first one, then what's your taxonomy registration code?

Comment: @SallyCJ I just want to change the link text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean, how to change the link's *text*, then you can change it when you register your taxonomy, by setting the **`back_to_items` label** to whatever text you like. Excerpt from the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#additional-parameter-information):

> - ‘**back_to_items’**  – the text displayed after a term has been updated for a link back to main index. Default is  `__( '← Back to tags' )`  or  `__( '← Back to categories' )`

So for example:

```php
register_taxonomy( 'shows', 'post', array(
    'public'            => true,
    'labels'            => array(
        'name'          => 'Shows',
        'singular_name' => 'Show',
        'back_to_items' => __( '&larr; Go to Shows', 'text-domain' ),
        // other labels
    ),
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    // your other args
) );
```

If you are unable to change/set the label during the taxonomy registration, e.g. because the taxonomy is being registered by a plugin, you can use the [`registered_taxonomy_<taxonomy>` or `registered_taxonomy` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#hooks) to override the taxonomy labels (and other args).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. That is exactly what I was looking for.